# Android layout placeholder for dynamically added view

Tags: android, android-layout

In my Android Activity, I need to add a single View dynamically (at runtime), at a specific position in a layout. The view to be added is determined at runtime. For example, may layout may look something like this:

```
<LinearLayout ...>
    <TextView ... />
    <!-- Dynamic item to be added here -->
    <TextView ... />
</LinearLayout>
```

What is the best way to achieve this?

One solution is to use `layout.addView(view, index)`, but I'd prefer not to hardcode the index.

Another solution is to use a FrameLayout as a placeholder, and place may dynamic view inside the FrameLayout, for example:

```
<LinearLayout ...>
    <TextView ... />
    <FrameLayout android:id="@+id/placeholder" />
    <TextView ... />
</LinearLayout>
```

Then:

```
findViewById(R.id.placeholder).addView(view);
```

However, this adds an unnecessary view in the hierarchy.

What would be the recommended way to do this?

Answer (score 14, accepted):

I think that using a FrameLayout as a placeholder for your view "added at runtime" is a good solution.

I would not worry about the impact of the extra "unnecesssary" view on performance.

Comment: Thanks. I ended up using `findViewById(R.id.placeholder).addView(view);`, where the placeholder may be a FrameLayout, or any other layout if the view should just be added at the end, such as a ScrollView.

Comment: you may get a deep tree of nested views like that, which might result in some cases with stuckoverflowerror, due to the limited stacksize for the UI thread

Answer (score 11):

You can also achieve this "lazy include" behaviour by using a `ViewStub`, as described in this (rather old) [article](http://android-developers.blogspot.com/2009/03/android-layout-tricks-3-optimize-with.html) from Android Developers.

Comment: For "lazy include" you need to specify the layout file to include at compile time, but I need to be able to add one of a number of views (determined at runtime). I edited the question to clarify.

Comment: The layout file specified in the ViewStub can be an empty LinearLayout, RelativeLayout, ... WhateverLayout that can be dynamically populated with any number of .AddView()'s. I don't see why this wouldn't work as you mentioned above (I'm actually implementing this now)

Comment: ViewStub stub = (ViewStub) findViewById(R.id.container_stub);
        stub.setLayoutResource(R.layout.activity_home);

Comment: about ViewStub  http://developer.android.com/reference/android/view/ViewStub.html  thanks for the link.

Answer (score 2):

You can use addView(View child, int index) without hard coding the exact index.

If one of the view's neighbors can be fixed (for example there is a specific label just before the place you want to insert the item), you can get the index of that view, and insert your dynamic view after that:

```
View previousView = findViewById(ID_OF_PREVIOUS_VIEW);
ViewGroup parent = (ViewGroup)previousView.getParent();
int previousIndex = parent.indexOfChild(previousView);
parent.addView(theDynamicallyCreatedView, previousIndex + 1);
```

Or you can use a ViewStub, but instead of inflating a layout, just remove it:

```
View placeholder = findViewById(ID_OF_STUB);
ViewGroup parent = (ViewGroup)previousView.getParent();
int index = parent.indexOfChild (placeholder);
parent.removeViewAt(index);
parent.addView(theDynamicallyCreatedView, index);
```

This way you won't end up with a huge view hierarchy.